# Matlab: How to random shuffle columns of matrix

Tags: arrays, matlab, random, matrix

I have a matrix like:

```
 A=
    4 7 8 9
    3 3 5 7
    6 4 8 6
```

and wants to random shuffle columns and do it something like:

```
 A=
    8 4 9 7
    5 3 7 3
    8 6 6 4
```

does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You can shuffle columns using indexing:

```
A(:,[3 1 4 2])
```

If you want to do it randomly, you can create a random permutation:

```
A(:,randperm(size(A,2)));
```