# Is there a better/faster way of randomly shuffling a matrix in MATLAB?

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

In MATLAB, I am using the shake.m function (http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/10067-shake) to randomly shuffle each column. For example:

```
a = [1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9]
a =

     1     2     3
     4     5     6
     7     8     9

b = shake(a)
b =

     7     8     6
     1     5     9
     4     2     3
```

This function does exactly what I want, however my columns are *very* long (>10,000,000) and so this takes a long time to run. Does anyone know of a faster way of achieving this? I have tried shaking each column vector separately but this isn't faster. Thanks!

Comment: Looking at that shake-function it appears to be fully vectorized, but it uses sort on a matrix column-wise. I.e. in your case it sorts columns with > 10,000,000 rows, which is unsurprisingly slow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a simple vectorized approach. Note that it creates an auxiliary matrix (`ind`) the same size as `a`, so depending on your memory it may be usable or not.

```
[~, ind] = sort(rand(size(a))); %// create a random sorting for each column
b = a(bsxfun(@plus, ind, 0:size(a,1):numel(a)-1)); %// convert to linear index
```

Comment: @Dan The idea (vectorized sorting) [came from you](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25547312/2586922) :-)

Comment: +1 Very interesting approach indeed! Well that `sort` proved to be the bottleneck in my solution.

Comment: +1 from me too. I have never seen shuffling done like this before.

Comment: @rayryeng Thanks! Actually that's what `randperm` does internally

Comment: @LuisMendo this is great - 1 second faster than Ben's suggestion and 10 seconds faster than Divakar's (when using `a = rand(10000000,5);`)!

Answer (score 8):

You can use `randperm` like this, but I don't know if it will be any faster than `shake`:

```
[m,n]=size(a)
for c = 1:n
    a(randperm(m),c) = a(:,c);
end
```

Or you can try switch the `randperm` around to see which is faster (should produce the same result):

```
[m,n]=size(a)
for c = 1:n
    a(:,c) = a(randperm(m),c);
end
```

Otherwise how many rows do you have? If you have far fewer rows than columns, it's possible that we can assume each permutation will be repeated, so what about something like this:

```
[m,n]=size(a)
cols = randperm(n);
k = 5;  %//This is a parameter you'll need to tweak...
set_size = floor(n/k);
for set = 1:set_size:n
    set_cols = cols(set:(set+set_size-1))
    a(:,set_cols) = a(randperm(m), set_cols);
end
```

which would massively reduce the number of calls to `randperm`. Breaking it up into `k` equal sized sets might not be optimal though, you might want to add some randomness to that as well. The basic idea here though is that there will only be `factorial(m)` different orderings, and if `m` is much smaller than `n` (e.g. `m=5`, `n=100000` like your data), then these orderings will be repeated naturally. So instead of letting that occur by itself, rather manage the process and reduce the calls to `randperm` which would be producing the same result anyway.

Comment: Thanks @Dan! I have 10,000,000 rows and 5 columns... I have done a quick profile summary on 1000 rows of data and your first two options are faster than shake already! Awesome. Will try the third suggestion.

Comment: @user2861089 watch out with the third, it might not be as random as the first two depending on the `k` parameter. You want each unique call to `randperm` to affect *on average* `n/factorial(m)` columns

Answer (score 5):

Obtain shuffled indices using randperm

```
idx = randperm(size(a,1));
```

Use the indices to shuffle the vector:

```
m = size(a,1);
for i=1:m
 b(:,i) = a(randperm(m,:);
end
```

Look at this answer: [Matlab: How to random shuffle columns of matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12384884/matlab-how-to-random-shuffle-columns-of-matrix)

Comment: @lakesh thanks for this - I'm not sure how I use this to actually achieve the output matrix I have above for b. I want to shuffle columns vertically, i.e. shake([1 4 7]); shake([2 5 8]); shake([3 6 9]);

Comment: @lakesh also if speed is an issue, it makes sense to calculate everything you can before the loop. So `size(a,1)` doesn't need to be calculated 10000000 times when it will always be the same.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a no-loop approach as it processes all indices at once and I believe this is as random as one could get given the requirements of shuffling among each column only.

**Code**

```
%// Get sizes
[m,n] = size(a);

%// Create an array of randomly placed sequential indices from 1 to numel(a)
rand_idx = randperm(m*n);

%// segregate those indices into rows and cols for the size of input data, a
col = ceil(rand_idx/m);
row = rem(rand_idx,m);
row(row==0)=m;

%// Sort both these row and col indices based on col, such that we have col
%// as 1,1,1,1 ...2,2,2,....3,3,3,3 and so on, which would represent per col
%// indices for the input data. Use these indices to linearly index into a
[scol,ind1] = sort(col);
a(1:m*n) = a((scol-1)*m + row(ind1))
```

Final output is obtained in `a` itself.

Comment: Thanks @Divakar - just tested this but not as fast as above answers. Thanks though!

Comment: @Divakar, please add an explanation - especially of you last line

Comment: @Dan Last line looks like a manual version of `sub2ind`. Doing it manually is usually faster than `sub2ind`.

Comment: @Dan Added comments. As Luis has pointed out the last line is basically a "raw" approach to `sub2ind` with inputs from `scol` and `row(ind1)` that are the sorted column and row indices.