# Parallel MATLAB - Create a distributed vector

Tags: arrays, matlab, distributed

I have a relativelly small vector in Matlab

```
R = randn(1,1000);
```

Now I would like to create a much bigger vector by selecting a specified set of elements like so

```
Q = R([1 5 8 5 8 1 3 4 19 1, etc]);
```

The number of the selected elements `numel(Q)` is 1,000,000+, very big. Is it possible to do this step such that the resulting vector `Q` is automatically a distributed array, ready for parallel processing on a multicore machine?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The approaches mentioned here assumes that you want to have at least `R` and `Q` as the distributed arrays.

**Approach #1**

This solution would be based on this [very smart solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25567017/3293881) -

```
N = 3;
R = randn(1,N,'distributed');
[~,ind] = sort(rand(numel(R)));
Q = R(ind(:));
```

Note that for the above code, `ind` would be on the client side. If you would like to have it as a distributed array too, use this -

```
N = 3;
R = randn(1,N,'distributed');
ind = ones(N,'distributed');
[~,ind(:,:)] = sort(rand(numel(R)));
Q = R(ind(:))
```

Output -

```
R =
    0.3080  0.8227  0.4248
Q =
    0.8227  0.3080  0.4248  0.4248  0.8227  0.3080  0.3080  0.4248  0.8227
```

In your case, `N = 1000`.

---

**Approach #2**

If you don't care about how many times an element from `R` is repeated in `Q`, then you may use this -

```
R = randn(1,N,'distributed');
Q = R(reshape(ceil(N*rand(N)),1,[]));
```

Comment: I'm sorry, how is Q a distributed array now? I need to do further operations on it and I want them to work in parallel on 16 cores

Comment: @AiridasKorolkovas If you only want to create a distributed vector, would this work after you create a normal vector, Q - `dQ = distributed(Q)`, where `dQ` represents your distributed vector?

Comment: Of course it would, but I think I could save half of the processing time by going to the distributed version directly. I'm thinking of something similar to building a sparse() matrix directly from non-zero entries, as opposed to first creating a full matrix and then converting to sparse.

Comment: @AiridasKorolkovas Just start with `R = randn(1,N,'distributed');` i.e. `R` is a distributed array and then `Q` would automatically become a distributed array. Thus, client side doesn't need to hold any data? Check out the edited code. Also, I am not sure why you need to use sparse matrices here given the problem you have in the question.