# Randperm columns of a matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

Hey i have a matrix A 3x3..

```
A= [1 2 3 4
    2 3 4 5
    3 4 5 6]
```

I want with randperm to generate a new matrix B where the columns will be shuflled..Anyone can help?

Comment: Give output sample also.It may convey more

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12384884/matlab-how-to-random-shuffle-columns-of-matrix

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `randperm` like this:

```
B = A(:, randperm(size(A,2)))
```

Comment: Why we use 2 in size(A,2) ?

Comment: You want to pass the number of columns to randperm (since you want it to return numbers in [1,4]). size(A, i) returns the size along the i-th dimension, so size(A, 1) is the number of rows, size(A,2) is the number of columns (and so on for matrices with more dimensions)